# Pentaho set field Value based on other field like in SQL

Tags: field, pentaho

How can I set a field value of a Row in Pentaho for a new or an existing field depending on values in other fields of the same row like in a SQL select statement.
Doing this with a filter would be to time intensive doing this with multiple fields.
For example:

[Price] = CASE WHEN [Price Sold] <> 1 THEN [Price Sold] ELSE [Price Bought] END

[FX Currency] = CASE WHEN [Ccy Sold] <> [RefCcy] THEN [Ccy Sold] ELSE [Ccy Bought] END

Comment: I think, you can set your answer as correct, as it also solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my problem by using a Step:

"User Defined Java Expression"

New Field   Java Expression
Price       Price_Sold!=1?Price_Sold:Price_Bought

Comment: You can also do this with the `Modified Javascript` step (javascript syntax) or the `Formula` step (Excel formula syntax). But your solution with a `Java expression` is best.